# I can use ajax from /edit but not from /detail

Tags: python, ajax, django

Django 1.10.

From DetailView I want to update the model object via ajax. Well, the model object is updated. But the ajax success function can't get data from the post method. I occur in failure function.

In other words, in Django in UpdateView I can stop at a breakpoint in form_valid, control that it returns an HttpResponse with code 200. And later if I refresh page with detail information, I can see that the model object has changed.

But in In Chrome dev tools while debugging js I occur in fail function. And jqXHR.status=0, textStatus = "error", errorThrown="".

I have prepared a simulation of my real situation:
https://Kifsif@bitbucket.org/Kifsif/ajax_update.git

There is a difference: this UpdateView renders the general_detail.html. In real life it should render partial_detail.html. Well, it is ajax, we don't need to reload the whole page.

So, this simulation renders the whole page. What does it mean? It means that:

1) If I'm in `http://localhost:8000/1/detail`, pressing AjaxEdit link leads me to the failure. Not working. In Chrome developers tools I occur in failure function.

2) I return to `http://localhost:8000/1/detail`, press Edit. I occur in `http://localhost:8000/1/edit`. This is ordinary editing without ajax. But the view is organized so that to render a response without redirect. So, I save the model and stay in **`http://localhost:8000/1/edit`**. And I can see the whole details as if I were looking at the result of a proper DetailView. There are two control links: Edit and AjaxEdit. **And now AjaxEdit starts working.**

In other words, at `http://localhost:8000/1/edit` ajax works, at `http://localhost:8000/1/detail` it doesn't.

I've just started learning ajax. I can't cope with this. I would say that a redirect may influence. But there is no redirect.

Via ajax I address to the get method of the view and get a proper data. What is the difference compared to post.

Could you comment on it and help me break through.

**views.py**

```
class GeneralUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = General
    fields = ['char']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return render(self.request, 'general/general_detail.html', {"object": self.object})
```

**models.py**

```
class General(models.Model):
    char = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={"pk": self.id})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^create$', GeneralCreate.as_view(), name="create"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/detail$', GeneralDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$', GeneralUpdate.as_view(), name="edit"),
]
```

**general_form.html**

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**general_detail.html**

```
<p id="char">{{ object.char }}</p>

<a href="{% url "edit" object.id %}">Edit</a>
<a id="ajax_edit" href="javascript:void(0)">AjaxEdit</a>


<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var ajax_edit = $("#ajax_edit");
    var char = $("#char");

    function show_get(data){
        $(data).insertAfter(char);
        var submit_link = $("#submit");
        submit_link.click(post);
    }

    function show_post(data){
        debugger;
    }

    function failure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        debugger;
    }

    function post(){
        $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/2/edit',
                success: show_post,
                error: failure,
                }
        )
    }

    function get(){
        $.ajax({
                method: "get",
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/2/edit',
                success: show_get,
                }
        )
    }

    ajax_edit.click(get);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly...

1. You click `AjaxEdit` - it fetches response from `UpdateView` and loads it directly into your `/detail` page. You technically still on `detail` page now.
2. You check your form in chrome dev and see that form `action` attribute points to nothing.
3. You click `Save` and your ajax request updates data as planned.
4. Then default submit happens and your `POST` request goes to `/detail` url since technically you are still on `details page`.
5. Django's `DetailView` forbids `POST` requests and kick it with 405 HTTP status (Method not Allowed), check it in chrome inspector.

So that's the main reason.

As a fix you can disable default submit action by adding

```
$("#form").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

before `submit_link.click(post);`

Comment: Thank you very much. Great answer.